# How to detect entity value changes (old/new) value on DocumentStore

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I want to log when a specific property on an entity changes from within a windows service.

I know RavenDB DocumentSession has this cool feature Advanced.WhatChanged(). This exposes old and new value on properties that changes in the session. That is really nice.

But my windows service is using DocumentStore which doesn't supply the same options for changetracking how do i implement the same mechanism?

From the documentation i can that i could implement a [Listener](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/listeners/what-are-listeners) or Subscribe to changes through the [Changes API](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/changes/what-is-changes-api) but they do not offer the functionality to see what property changed and what the old value was.

Comment: Not sure that I follow, you don't use sessions at all? WhatChanged() functionality strongly depends on session's object tracking, so without sessions it is not possible to use WhatChanged() at all.